# Appending dependsOn for a modules build task when the build task already exists

Tags: gradle, build, build.gradle

I have a Gradle multi-project. All the modules within the project pull in a custom plugin which defines the `build` task i.e all common build steps. They're all Java projects/modules.

In one of the projects, called `alt`, I'd like to specify that it's build should specifically depend on 2 other another tasks i.e `"app-bundle", "intern"`.

But when I set the following for `alt`, I get the error below.

What is the syntax for appending this additional `dependsOn` logic for `alt`'s build?

`build.gradle`:

```
val rootBuild = task("build") {
    dependsOn("app-bundle", "intern")
}
```

Error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/rob/git/root-project/alt/build.gradle.kts' line: 22

* What went wrong:
Cannot add task 'build' as a task with that name already exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

hope below example helps

```
task("custom1") {
    println("from custom task")
}

tasks["build"].dependsOn("custom1")
```